# how to extract coordinates (latitudes and longitudes) from a raster? using arcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, coordinates

I am a student working on my final year study. It's my first time using ArcGIS. 
I need to have the coordinates of the polygons that I choose to work on. 
After converting the zones that I created into a raster, I want to extract the coordinates.

Comment: I need the latitude and longitude of each polygone (maybe there center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.

1. If you want centroids, you can convert the raster to a polygon and get the centroids of the dataset
2. You can convert the raster to a numpy array (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) and use some simple math to figure out from the raster's origin and the width of the cells the locations you need.

There are a bunch of other ways to do it as well...

Comment: Good evening, I found the solution and it's very simple. I don't need to convert it in raster. I can let it as a vector and get the information.

Comment: This a video on youtube that showed me how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgIHXi6lxgo
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly compute the coordinates of a polygon stored as a raster, because pixels of a raster are not aware of the other pixels with this value. As you mentioned that you had to convert your polygons to raster, you should directly work in vector type: open the attribute table, create one field for long and one for lat, then compute the centroid X nd Y with "calculate geometry" after right-clicking on the fields name.